# Linux cannot connect to device using rs232 interface, Windows does not have problems

Tags: c++, linux, windows

This seems to work in Windows 7 when using a script+c/c++ socket program that connects to a device converter with an ip. 
However same program compiled in a linux environment is unable to send the command that would produce an output.
The command is FF€   the euro sign at the end is \x80 and means for the device EOT.

Most likely my Windows laptop uses cp1252 (or Windows-1252) conversion that produces with the extended ASCII \80 the euro sign. The vendor of device said that the last sign of command is programmed to be different than the ASCII first signs and this has been programmed as the "euro" sign.
In my C++ program I have used locale that sets the environment, but still it does not cured.
Could you please advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>      // Needed for memset
#include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for the socket functions
#include <netdb.h>      // Needed for the socket functions
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf-8");
//std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.iso88591");
//std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
//printf ("Locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE.iso88591") );
    int status;
    char* ip=argv[1];
//cout<<"hello ip:"<<&ip<<"\n";
    char* po=argv[2];
//cout<<"hello port"<<po<<"\n";
    char* co=argv[3];
//cout<<"hello "<<co<<"\n";

    struct addrinfo host_info;       // The struct that getaddrinfo() fills up with data.
    struct addrinfo *host_info_list; // Pointer to the to the linked list of host_info's.

    // The MAN page of getaddrinfo() states "All  the other fields in the structure pointed
    // to by hints must contain either 0 or a null pointer, as appropriate." When a struct
    // is created in c++, it will be given a block of memory. This memory is not nessesary
    // empty. Therefor we use the memset function to make sure all fields are NULL.
    memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof host_info);

//    std::cout << "Setting up the structs..."  << std::endl;
//   std::cout << "Das ist es ip"<<&ip;
//   std::cout << "Das ist der zweite<<&po;

    host_info.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;     // IP version not specified. Can be both.
    host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // Use SOCK_STREAM for TCP or SOCK_DGRAM for UDP.

    // Now fill up the linked list of host_info structs with google's address information.
    status = getaddrinfo(ip, po, &host_info, &host_info_list);                  // handelt die generierung und verbindung zum socket (egal ob IPv4 or IPv6) return 0 if successful
   // getaddrinfo returns 0 on succes, or some other value when an error occured.
    // (translated into human readable text by the gai_gai_strerror function).
    if (status != 0)  std::cout << "getaddrinfo error" << gai_strerror(status) ;


//    std::cout << "Creating a socket..."  << std::endl;
    int socketfd ; // The socket descripter
    socketfd = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype,
                      host_info_list->ai_protocol);                                             //generiere socket und gibt -1 bei fehler
    if (socketfd == -1)  std::cout << "socket error " ;


//    std::cout << "Connect()ing..."  << std::endl;
    status = connect(socketfd, host_info_list->ai_addr, host_info_list->ai_addrlen);            //verbinde zum server und gibt -1 bei fehler
    if (status == -1)  std::cout << "connect error" ;


//    std::cout << "send()ing message..."  << std::endl;
//    const char* co2="\xe2\x82\xac";
    //const char* co2="\x0D";
//    const char* co2="\x80\b\x04^D\x0d^M\n\v\f";
    //int ne=128;
    //char c=(char) ne;
    //char* co2=&c;
    const char* co2="\x80";
    cout<<"Das ist das EOT Zeichen\n"<<co2;

    char* msg=new char[strlen(co)+strlen(co2)+1];
    strcpy(msg,co);
    strcat(msg,co2);
    std::cout <<"\nThis is what the command is:\t" <<msg<<"\n";
    //char str[80];
    //strcpy(str,co);
    //strcat(str,co2);
    //std::cout <<"\nThis is what the command is:\t" <<str <<"\n";
    int len;
    ssize_t bytes_sent;
    len = strlen(msg);
    bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg, len, 0);                                                   //sende und empfange daten
//    std::cout << "Waiting to recieve data..."  << std::endl;
    ssize_t bytes_recieved;
    char incomming_data_buffer[10000];
    bytes_recieved = recv(socketfd, incomming_data_buffer,10000, 0);                            //Empfange daten in speicher und mache mit programm weiter falls keine daten geschickt werden
    // If no data arrives, the program will just wait here until some data arrives.
    if (bytes_recieved == 0) std::cout << "host shut down." << std::endl ;
    if (bytes_recieved == -1)std::cout << "recieve error!" << std::endl ;
//    std::cout << bytes_recieved << " bytes recieved :" << std::endl ;
    incomming_data_buffer[bytes_recieved] = '\0' ;
    std::cout << incomming_data_buffer << std::endl;
//    std::cout << "Receiving complete. Closing socket..." << std::endl;
//    sleep (2);
    freeaddrinfo(host_info_list);                                                               //free memory
    close(socketfd);                                                                            //schliesse socket
}
```

Comment: As a first step, I would run Wireshark in Windows, and Wireshark in Linux, and run each program, and observe what the actual bytes being sent to the device are.

Comment: PS, should not that be `+1` not `+0` where you allocate `msg` ?

Comment: Ok, changed it to :char* msg=new char[strlen(co)+strlen(co2)+1]; Sorry, but what does the 0 or +1 stands for? The msg allocation:     bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg, len, 0);

Comment: You need room for the terminating 0 byte added by strcat...

Comment: The data in wireshark is unfortunately encrypted. Guess this is the ssh overlay. Comparing the both compiled executables with od, would that be an option? Please let me know the command if you know better. I was also hearing that the glibc might be preconfigured for character enconding. Any ideas on this as well? Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Is there something similar on Linux SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);  SetConsoleCP(1251);

Comment: You might need to post a bit more info, i.e. exactly what is not working as expected: e.g. is the device sending back nothing, or an error message, or garbage? Maybe paste a trace of your console when you run the program, from both Windows and Linux...
Note, I would have thought that "\x80" would produce a binary 0x80 in your output, strcat is not exactly complicated...

Comment: Why don't you simply open the tty file directly? Why wrapping it in a SSL-encrypted network connection?

Answer (score 0):

(For Linux only) if you need to see a hexdump of what is being sent by send(), insert the following code:

```
FILE *f = popen( "od -Ax -tx1z -v", "w");
fwrite( msg, 1, len, f); 
fclose(f);
```

Repeat to see what comes back:

```
f = popen( "od -Ax -tx1z -v", "w");
fwrite( incomming_data_buffer, 1, bytes_recieved, f); 
fclose(f);
```

On Windows you will need to just do a loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < len; i++) { printf("%02x ", msg[i]; } printf("\n");
```

[Posted as answer to get formatting]

Comment: Of course, on linux you can do the loop too. The `popen` method will just give you additional formatting.

Comment: I have always found using od and being able to quickly change formatting to suit the problem at hand extremely useful, especially for visually spotting patterns in big dumps

Comment: Personally, I prefer `xxd`. But your answer just makes it appear to be more complicated on linux, while in fact linux allows the same approach, but also gives you additional options such as piping the data to an external hexdumper.

Comment: Windows 7 Laptop (using cygwin) Hexdump:
================================================
$ /home/kocak/C/final/final/DTR_client_SignalLevel2.exe 127.0.0.1 11000 KK
K

kocak@GFR-000109 ~/C/final/final
$ 000000 4b 4b 80                                         >KK.<
000003
000000 4b                                               >K<
000001

Comment: Linux server Hexdump :
================================================
kocakh@kpimon02:~/DTR/final> ./DTR_RS232_socket.run 172.16.115.74 1024 KK
K-0675-
000000 4b 4b 80                                         >KK.<
000003
000000 4b 2d 30 36 37 35 2d                             >K-0675-<
000007

Comment: Windows 7 Laptop (using cygwin) expected output:
================================================
kocak@GFR-000109 ~/C/final/final
$ /home/kocak/C/final/final/DTR_client_SignalLevel2.exe 127.0.0.1 11000 KK
K

kocak@GFR-000109 ~/C/final/final
$ /home/kocak/C/final/final/DTR_client_SignalLevel2.exe 127.0.0.1 11000 KK
675-0

kocak@GFR-000109 ~/C/final/final
$ /home/kocak/C/final/final/DTR_client_SignalLevel2.exe 127.0.0.1 11000 KK
K-0675-                       SO THE EXPECTED OUTPUT IS (or PART) OF: K-0675-0675**bold**

Comment: Of what I can see from the above output is that the Linux server sends the expected data, but it does NOT outputs it right on console. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It looks as if the buffer when receive socket is initiated, the data is obsolete. Still struggling...

Comment: Ok seems to be working with the above suggestion. I will let you know more soon. I need just to understand the why. THX